# Show all images in folder in Laravel 5.6 with blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, slideshow

I have a page made with pure PHP. Now I want to do it with Laravel and Blade. I have this code in PHP to view a slideshow of images that are inside a folder but I do not know how to do this with Laravel. The main problem is access to the images folder.
This is the pure PHP code:

```
$dirname = "../img/folder/";
$images = glob($dirname . "*.png");
foreach ($images as $image) {
                        echo '
                        <div class="mySlides">
                        <img class="slide-img" src="' . $image . '"
                             style="width:100%">
                        <div class="text"></div>
                    </div>
                    ';
                    }
```

Here is the folder where I want to take the images:
[image]

And I have the views with the following structure (indicated the view that shows the images):
[image]
single.blade.php extends from default.blade.php

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have it(the image name) saved in a database?

Comment: No, all images are in public/images/anyfolder

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can access it with the `asset()` function in your blade files.
In general, you could do it like this:

`asset('/images/infotest/nameOfImage')`

Comment: If i do that in the controller i get this error:

InvalidArgumentException
The "http://localhost:8000/images/folder" directory does not exist.

Comment: Hi, i have edited my answer. Please check again. Perheps you needed the / in the beginning. And check the name of the folder you use. @Br0wn

Comment: Im trying this in my controller but doesn´t work. I have to say im new in Laravel. 
public function single(Application $application){

        $directory = asset('/images/infotest/');
        $images = File::allFiles($directory);

        return view('projects.single', ['application' => $application, 'images' => $images]);
    }

And i have this error anyway: 
The "http://localhost:8000/images/infotest" directory does not exist.

Comment: I need return an array and after in the view, show all images with  a bucle.

Comment: As i said, you need to do it in your view, not in the controller. do you have the name of the image stored in your database? @Br0wn

Comment: I have saved the name of the folder in the database that is the same name as each project. I want to use is name of the database to make a dynamic view